# Changing from Through hole to Surface mount component

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, emi-filtering, ground-plane

I have a design that would require a flat backing of our pcb. We are attaching a flex pcb to the back of this board being designed. This caused me to move/change some components from another engineers design that was 100 % functional to account for this.

Key notes:
1)
The ground plane from the original design encompasses all components except for the VDD on L2 (top left).
2) I changed C1D from the through hole component to our surface mount capacitor.
3)
100V 47 uF capacitor, POE application.

Question(s):

1. Does the new ground plane/ design pose any issues, as VDD is 48 V and pgnd is for our POE devices before the transformer. I am looking specifically at the pours of VDD and PGND on the left of the component C1D. ex. This would create some sort of noise/EMI issue.
2. Can someone give me a brief reasoning why/ why not I would want to encompass our components with ground pour?

Original
[image: Through Hole design]
Surface Mount Design

[image: Surface Mount Design]

Comment: If ground is PGND then it looks a poor design to me. Get as much as you can from the ground plane side and no need to create problems on the top layer by adding to the ground plane on that side.

Comment: How so? What is the issue, I cant understand without some context.

Comment: I added it to my 1st comment. We also need context such as what the design layers originally looked like before changing to SMD. If necessary go for a 4-layer PCB.

Comment: In other words you have a compromised ground-pane on both sides and this won't cut the mustard.

Comment: I see, the before and after are attached, click either, it appears as one image at first glance. I can stick to the single side for pgnd, is that recommended? The original creator stitched the entire board top and bottom, encompassing the components using the ground sections with a pour.

Comment: What is compromising the ground exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152185/discussion-between-wes-ellgass-and-andy-aka).

Comment: The fact that it is not as close to near 100% coverage as possible. You should research about how to design a ground plane; it's common knowledge.

Comment: Since I am not as experienced as the previous designer I want to keep the design as close to the original, but I understand the concept of a ground plane. Luckily they have poured ground on both sides and via stitched. Is that an issue? Still I must wonder if the changes I made could be detrimental.

Comment: Put ground one one side and tracks on the other for most normal designs. Splitting = compromise. It would be a mistake to make it close to the original because, you will have something degraded somewhere so, start from scratch and adopt best practice.